# Struts tags substitution

Tags: html, struts2, struts, html-parsing, struts-1

I was wondering if I could replace Struts tags with HTML, especially when I output data. The projects in my company are still using struts tags but it seems it's not so easy to use compared with HTML.

Comment: I don't see why this was down voted so upvoting to balance it out. It seems to be a very straightforward to the point question.

And yes you can Struts tags just mask a lot of the HTML to make the code more readable and concise. But you could write out all of that HTML if you wanted which one of the other answers goes more indepth about.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, as long as you duplicate:

- Whatever HTML is emitted by the tag, and...
- ...whatever Java logic the tag implements.

For example, all custom form tags do is:

- Emit form elements
- (possibly embedded in other markup depending on your S2 theme)
- Set the form element value from an action property
- Display any error messages relating to the form element (depending on your S2 theme)

Some tags don't emit any HTML of their own, for example, `<s:iterator>` loops over a collection, pushes each object onto the value stack, and processes the tag body like any other JSP custom tag.

*Should* you reproduce existing framework logic and write either:

- A *lot* more HTML, or...
- ...your own complete suite of custom tags?

I doubt it, but there are likely valid usecases for doing so–I just can't think of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Dave. If I need display the data, for example in value stack or action form. As struts tags run in server side, I assume js wont work. So what technique will work it out?